# Is it possible to enable Windows aero inside a Ubuntu VM?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, desktop-customization, wine

I'm trying to switch from Windows to Ubuntu, but some of my favorite programs don't run on Windows.
Steam is fine because of the new Proton function etc. But unfortunately "Wallpaperengine" is not working inside Ubuntu because it needs "Aero" to be enabled, but I don't know how I should manage to solve this.
I even tried to run Wallpaper engine inside of wine, but this doesn't help either.
I'm Using wine 5.0.1, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-Bit and Proton 5.0-9.

Comment: If Wallpaperengine doesn’t support WINE then you are out of luck.  The system requirements specifically implies that Ubuntu (Linux) isn’t supported by the application

Comment: Too sad. The creator of Wallpapereninge said, that he doesn't want to support Linux because of the few users (like 1%)

Comment: I have both Ubuntu and Kali guest machines here and the Windows features you want are not in Linux (that I can see). Most of what I need is in Windows.  Unity mode (VMware) for Windows guests does not work in Linux either.

Comment: Possibly... install the Linux Windows 7 theme.

Comment: Do you know how? I try it my self for sure, but need some googling first